# Write a `long line test` for visual basic in python (`LineLengthBear` of coala)

Tags: python, python-3.x, coala, coala-bears

Here's my code,

```
invalid_VB_file = """
'C' * (65535 + 1)
"""

LineLengthBearLangSpecificAspectTest = verify_local_bear(
    LineLengthBear,
    valid_files=(test_file,),
    invalid_files=(invalid_VB_file,),
    aspects=AspectList([
        get_aspect('LineLength')('VisualBasic', max_line_length=4),
        ]),
    settings={'language': 'VisualBasic'},
        )
```

So basically, it ignores `max_line_length=4` and picks up the already defined limit of 65535 for the Visual Basic file. The problem I am facing is the LineLengthBear gives me 18 as the length of the line in `invalid_VB_test` and renders the test as valid, thus, the test fails. Is there any way to write an invalid test i.e. a line longer than 65535 characters, without literally writing such a long line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is literally `"'C' * (65535 + 1)"`. If you actually want a line of 65536 Cs, then take it out of the quotes:

```
invalid_VB_file = 'C' * (65535 + 1)
```